# IfElse with multiple Statements Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I use IfElse with multiple Statements to get print different datas if the ComboBox change the item:

For example:

```
 Sub Vesselget()
    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Cairebelle Jayde" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "CBJ"

        ElseIf
        vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Colan James" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "CNJ"

        ElseIf
        vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Felicity Mackenzie" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "FEM"

        ElseIf
        vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Lauren Danrya" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "LAD"

        ElseIf
        vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Mackenzie Maria" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "MAM"

        ElseIf
        vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Sophia Shay" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "SSH"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of ComboBox is that (which UI Platform)? What is its data source? -- You can just get the `SelectedValue` to set `vesselprint.Text`, if data binding is initialized correctly. Or another property of the selected data-bound item. For sure, you don't use an `If` condition for each item in a ComboBox. Note that `vesselprint.Text` can also be bound to the same source of data, then no need to do anything: when an Item is selected, the text changes automatically.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studios 2019, and not using any data source. But thanks for the comment...

Comment: Well, Visual Studio is not an UI Platform. I mean WinForms, WPF etc. And, yes, you have a *data source*, given the strings you're handling. In its simplest form, it's a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`. If you use a Dictionary as the data source of your ComboBox, you don't need any code to set values in other Controls bound to the same data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to do this.  If you defined a common data source between the controls, as the combobox selected a different item, this would be reflected in the vesselprint textbox if bound to same datasource.  Neater for larger data sets.

If you don't want to use a datasource and prefer to code it all yourself, you can write your first example as:

```
    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Cairebelle Jayde" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "CBJ"
    ElseIf vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Colan James" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "CNJ"
    ElseIf vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Felicity Mackenzie" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "FEM"
    ElseIf vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Lauren Danrya" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "LAD"
    ElseIf vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Mackenzie Maria" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "MAM"
    ElseIf vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Sophia Shay" Then
        vesselprint.Text = "SSH"
    End If
```

So you were nearly there, just lose the line breaks.  Or alternatively you could use  do this:

```
  Private Function GetVesselPrint(SelectedItem As String) As String
    Select Case SelectedItem
        Case "Cairebelle Jayde"
            Return "CBJ"
        Case "Colan James"
            Return "CNJ"
        Case "Cairebelle Jayde"
            Return "CBJ"
        Case "Felicity Mackenzie"
            Return "FEM"
        Case "Lauren Danrya"
            Return "LAD"
        Case "Mackenzie Maria"
            Return "MAM"
        Case "Sophia Shay"
            Return "SSH"
        Case Else
            Return Nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

which you would call like this:

```
vesselprint.Text = GetVesselPrint(vesselcmb.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. Thanks a lot. Looks more easier.

Answer (score 0):

So Guys, I used the old methods that I know and fixed my problem. It has been a long time since I programmed in VB.net.

```
            Dim CBJ As String = "CBJ"
Dim CNJ As String = "CNJ"
Dim FEM As String = "FEM"
Dim LAD As String = "LAD"
Dim MAM As String = "MAM"
Dim SSH As String = "SSH"


If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Cairebelle Jayde" Then
        vesselprint.Text = CBJ
    End If

    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Colan James" Then
        vesselprint.Text = CNJ
    End If

    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Felicity Mackenzie" Then
        vesselprint.Text = FEM
    End If

    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Lauren Danrya" Then
        vesselprint.Text = LAD
    End If

    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Mackenzie Maria" Then
        vesselprint.Text = MAM
    End If

    If vesselcmb.SelectedItem = "Sophia Shay" Then
        vesselprint.Text = SSH
    End If
```